# Select specific mesh in obj file or edit file

Tags: 3d, mesh, .obj, babylonjs, meshlab

I bought a 3d mesh pack [here](https://free3d.com/3d-model/house-interior-items-pack-extended-6713.html) but I'm confused with how to load the objects in this pack one-by-one. I load them into my Babylon game with this:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "./", "./resources/objects/house pack.obj", scene, function (newMeshes) { } )
```

But it loads the entire mesh like in the first screenshot of the link above. Sorry, kind of a noob with using meshes but am I able to load submeshes in there individually? Or all at once but with some way to parse one from the other? If not, any idea how I can easily edit the mesh to create separate files with each mesh? I tried meshlab but it keeps crashing and behaving weirdly.

Answer (score 0):

Supossing that your input obj file is organized in groups, SceneLoader.ImportMesh loads the meshes from the file and appends them to the scene. The first parameter can be set to null to load all meshes, or you can give a list of meshes of your interest

```js
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(["chair1", "desk1"], "./", "./resources/objects/house pack.obj", scene, function (newMeshes) 
{
    // do something with the meshes
    var meshes = newmeshes.meshes;
    var materials = newMeshes.materials;
});
```

You need to know a list of the meshes inside of the collection, listed in the manual of your assets or reading the house pack.obj file with an editor.

Also, you can instead use SceneLoader.LoadAssetContainer to load all  assets from the file and does not append them to the scene until later.

```js
BABYLON.SceneLoader.LoadAssetContainer("./", "house pack.obj", scene, function (container) {
    var meshes = container.meshes;
    var materials = container.materials;
    //...

    // Adds all elements to the scene
    container.addAllToScene();
});
```

Comment: If I try out the second snippet you mentioned and add a "console.log(meshes)" in there, the output is an array of length 1 that has an object with a bunch of different properties. Does this mean that my obj file is not set up in the proper way to parse the items apart or is an array of length 1 expected and i need to dig into one of the properties in that object to get to the submeshes?

Comment: Can't say without see the file. I suppose that the file is organized in groups inside (lines starting with letter g in the obj file)

Comment: yeah I opened up the file and there is only one line starting with g that says "g g0". So I guess it's all in one group :/

Comment: Then your next option is load the file in meshlab or blender and manually separate into several independent .obj files. Easy if you are interested in one or two assets, and tedious if you want separate every asset in the file.